# Wait until pyscript packages are fully loaded and then modify the DOM

Tags: python, pyscript

I want to wait until pyscript has fully loaded all packages and after that alter an element on the DOM.

I tried using `window.addEventListener('load', create_proxy(func))` in pyscript. But to no avail, it does not execute the function. I also tried adding the event listener `'change'` to the element that is being modified by pyscript. The element is used for inserting a table using the `panel` package. After the table is inserted I'd like to remove another element on the page.

Any help appreciated

Comment: That DOM event has already been triggered before PyScript starts loading.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic way is to use pyscript.write().

```html
<html>
    
    <head>
            
        <title>Pyscript - Test</title>
     
    <!-- Load required PyScript packages -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.css" />
        <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.js"onerror=scriptLoadFailure('pyscr ipt.js')></script>

<py-env>
- pandas
</py-env>

    </head>
    
<!-- ------------------------------------------------------------------- -->
    <body>
        
<py-script>
import pandas as pd
def do_it():
    df = pd.DataFrame([[12, 14, 10, 11, 1], [22, 24, 20, 21, 0]])
    pyscript.write('output', df)
    pyscript.write('msg', 'That should be it')
do_it()
</py-script>
        <header id="header_top">Pyscript - Test</header>
        <div id="main1">
            <div id="output">
                Testing div with id="output" 
            </div>
            <div id="msg"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
<!-- ------------------------------------------------------------------- -->
</html>
```

While loading the content of the paage is
**Pyscript - Test

Testing div with id="output"**

After loading has finished there is a pandas df in the output div and additional text in a separate div with id="msg"
*"That should be it"*    Regards...
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Run this in JS before you load any of the pyscript packages.

```
pyscriptLoaded = false

// Store the original console.log function
const originalConsoleLog = console.info;

// Override the console.log function with a custom one
console.info = function (message) {
  originalConsoleLog.apply(console, arguments); // Call the original console.log function

  if (message.includes('PyScript page fully initialized')) {
    pyscriptLoaded = true;
    console.log = originalConsoleLog;
  }
};
```

It intercepts the console log messages and find when it has compelted loading